# How can I build my python project with all the files that i need?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, matplotlib, build

I finished a project I've been working on for I while, but when I build it using pyinstaller it doesn't work on different machines(You can see the error down below). I guess it is because of modules I imported into the project: sympy, numpy, matplotlib,and tkinter. So how can I build it so it becomes self-sufficient, with no need to download any other module or library?

(I built it in linux because i want it to run on linux machine. I didn't face any problem with building it into windows exe)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "matplotlib/__init__.py", line 923, in <module>
  File "matplotlib/__init__.py", line 608, in matplotlib_fname
RuntimeError: Could not find matplotlibrc file; your Matplotlib install is broken
[8025] Failed to execute script main
```

Comment: Please don't repost (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68329580/module-not-found-after-building-python-project-by-using-pysinstaller). If someone knows a solution they will answer. Also reposting can be confusing when people have the same problem (they will find 2 pages and have to search the correct one (where there is a solution))

Comment: I just need the answer so baad :((